# Swift userdefaults not storing value

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to present an alert when the user number of posts is 5 in Firestore. I am trying to use userdefaults to store true when the alert has been shown so it does not keep getting displayed when the view controller is presented. However when I try to check using this code it still displays the alert every time so I assume the user defaults value is not changing to true. Anyone know why this would be happening?

```
 private func checkDueReview(){
    if User.currentUser() != nil {
        let alertShown = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ShownAlert")
    
    let currentUser = User.currentUser()!
        
        if alertShown == false && currentUser.numberOfPosts == 5{
                self.present(reviewAlert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ShownAlert")
        }else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "ShownAlert")
        }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: If alertShown is ever true, you are resetting it to false and if they still have 5 posts, then you show it again.

Comment: Have you checked the number of posts of the user instead assuming that the UserDefaults value is not changing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your second if condition where you perform 2 checks but the else is only valid for the second one, `currentUser.numberOfPosts == 5` (did you mean >= 5 btw?)

So I would change it to

```
if currentUser.numberOfPosts == 5 {
    if alertShown == false {
        self.present(reviewAlert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ShownAlert")
    }
} else {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "ShownAlert")
}
```

There are some other improvements that can be made to your code like replacing the first `if` with a `guard` statement and use `!` when checking for false

```
guard let currentUser = User.currentUser() else { return }
let alertShown = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ShownAlert")

if currentUser.numberOfPosts == 5 {
    if !alertShown {
        self.present(reviewAlert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ShownAlert")
    }
} else {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "ShownAlert")
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks seems to work now, do I even need the else?

Comment: I got rid of the else and it seems to work now

Comment: It depends, can the number of post decrease? If not then the `else` is probably not needed